# when I try to loop array in render function in react.js, it shows nothing, why?

Tags: reactjs

Here is a code:

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div
            <div className="container-center">
                <div className="container-center-inner">

                    <div>
                        <div className="container-checkout">
                            <div>
                                <div className="container-cart">
                                {
                                    this.props.cartStore.items.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {


                                        return (
                                            <div className="basket-item" key={i}>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div className="basket-item-image">
                                                        <TShirt className="color-tshirt-small" width="130" height="176" images={item.cartItemTShirt.image} color={item.item.color} />
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        )

                                    })
                                }
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Container "container-cart" is empty, but this.props.cartStore.items has values, and should work. When I try to execute code before return of render, the all working fine, but when I place it into return, it returns nothing. I think something wrong in loop, but I dont know, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `<div>` in your return statement is missing a closing tag (`>`).

I'd recommend cutting a lot of the superfluous tags or compartmentalising your component hierarchy to make such debugging easier in the future.

Also, convention is to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) rather than `forEach()` to return an `array` of components.

See below for a complete example.

```
// Render.
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container-center">
        <div className="container-center-inner">
          <div>
            <div className="container-checkout">
              <div>
                <div className="container-cart">
                  {this.props.cartStore.items.map((item, i, arr) => {
                    return (
                      <BasketItem item={item} i={i}/>
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

// Basket Item.
const BasketItem = ({item, i, arr}) => (
  <div className="basket-item" key={i}>
    <div>
      <div className="basket-item-image">
          <TShirt className="color-tshirt-small" width="130" height="176" images={item.cartItemTShirt.image} color={item.item.color} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: It also worth to mention that forEach does not return an array but map does, and this is what makes difference.